# What is the intuitive meaning of the capacity of a timing channel?

Tags: information-theory, queueing-theory

I am studying a timing channel. A queue can act as a noise source to such systems as it will disturb the information coded in the incoming time. If the queue has a deterministic service time than we can transfer the messages with larger time gaps than the service time and obtain no noise and hence the Capacity will be infinite.
My doubt is:

The capacity is the maximum rate at which we can transfer the information. How for a transmission scheme that increases the time gap between transmitting messages, can the rate be infinite? I am just uncomfortable with this concept.

Comment: how do you conclude that the capacity is infinite?

Comment: I get in the paper :
https://www.princeton.edu/~verdu/reprints/Bits%20Through%20Queues.pdf

Comment: I apologise but I only see that it is finite, in units bits/channel use which is the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

If the queue has deterministic service time $t_0$ you can look at the received time $r_k$ for the $k^{th}$ packet and noiselessly obtain $$x_k=r_k-t_0$$ thus achieving channel capacity which is still finite in the proper units of bits/channel use.